# Passing a Vec<Struct> into a new task

Tags: task, rust, lifetime

Im attempting to pass a `Vector` of a custom struct into a function that is executed in a new task.  I've implemented the `Clone` trait, which I thought was needed for this, but apparently the vector I want to pass in needs to implement `'static+Send` in order to be captured in the closure's environment.  I'm not exactly sure how to go about satisfying those lifetime specs?

I'm attempting to start the process from this function

```
pub fn start(server: Server, ip: &str, port: u16) {

    // Other things happening

    spawn(proc() {
        event_loop(server.events.clone(), from_conn_pool)
    });
}

fn event_loop(events: Vec<Event>, from_conn_pool: Receiver<Vec<Socket>>) {
    // Wizard magic
}
```

The error I receive is: `error: cannot capture variable of type rustic_io::server::Server<'_>, which does not fulfill 'static+Send, in a bounded closure`

**server.rs**

```
pub struct Server<'a> {
    pub sockets: Vec<Socket<'a>>,
    pub events: Vec<Event<'a>>
}
```

**event.rs**

```
pub struct Event<'a> {
    pub name: String,
    pub execute: &'a fn(data: &str, server: super::Server)
}

impl<'a> Event<'a> {
    pub fn new(event: &str, execute: &'a fn(data: &str, server: super::Server)) -> Event<'a> {
        Event {
            name: String::from_str(event),
            execute: execute
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Clone for Event<'a> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Event<'a> {
        Event {
            name: self.name.clone(),
            execute: self.execute
        }
    }
}
```

The event loop task will just loop over various streams and if data is read that matches a certain event name, it fires off the function associated with it.  From the Rust documentation, I can see that you can start a named function off by calling spawn like so:

```
// Print something profound in a different task using a named function
fn print_message() { println!("I am running in a different task!"); }
spawn(print_message);
```

Which, I believe is the way I should be spawning the task, because it is a named function that is getting executed.  Im assuming that because I'm calling it as `spawn(proc(){ ... })`, it is expecting everything going in to be closure-ownable?  I've tried spawning the task as `spawn(event_loop(arg, arg2))`, but the compiler gives me: `error: mismatched types: expected proc():Send but found () (expected fn but found ())`

At this point, I've got no idea how to get that `Vec<Event>` into a new task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `proc()` owns its environment. Anything coming into it must be able to be moved into it and must thus be `'static` and `Send`.

This means that when you write

```
spawn(proc() {
    event_loop(server.events.clone(), from_conn_pool)
});
```

it is trying to capture `server` (because of `server.events.clone()`—note how it’s capturing the entire `Server` for this purpose; it’s unlikely to be what you wanted (you can do something like `let events = server.events.clone();` before the proc and then use `events`, or you can just acknowledge that the `clone()` call is superfluous anyway) and `from_conn_pool`. Your problem is with `server`: it is not necessarily `'static`, because you didn’t specify any lifetime for the type and so it is inferred as an arbitrary lifetime; that is, it may contain an event of non-static lifetime, which evidently can’t be moved to a new task. You would for starters need `Server<'static>`.

But the question then rises: why are you using `&'a fn(…)` rather than just `fn(…)` as your type? If you drop the whole reference thing there, your problem will go away.

Comment: My first attempt at this, I had a vector of closures instead of named functions.  And in order to have that, I needed a lifetime specifier.  Once I learned that closures could not be clone, I changed them to `fn()` and just assumed because the closure vector needed a lifetime specifier, the fn type would as well.  Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: No, a function has no environment and so no need for any lifetimes.