# "the type does not fulfill the required lifetime" when using a method in a thread

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am trying to use a method in a thread in Rust, but I get the following error message

> :21:10: 21:23 error: the type `[closure@<anon>:21:24: 23:14
>   tx:std::sync::mpsc::Sender<i32>, self:&MyStruct, adder:i32, a:i32]`
>   does not fulfill the required lifetime :21
>   thread::spawn(move || {
>                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~ :18:9: 24:10 note: in this expansion of for loop expansion note: type must outlive the static
>   lifetime error: aborting due to previous error

This is the example code:

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc;

struct MyStruct {
    field: i32
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn my_fn(&self, adder1: i32, adder2: i32) -> i32 {
        self.field + adder1 + adder2
    }

    fn threade_test(&self) {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
        let adder = 1;
        let lst_adder = vec!(2, 2, 2);

        for a in lst_adder {
            let tx = tx.clone();

            thread::spawn(move || {
                let _ = tx.send(self.my_fn(adder, a));
            });
        }

        println!("{}", rx.recv().unwrap());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ms = MyStruct{field: 42};
    ms.threade_test();
}
```

[Test it on the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4aa91b2de99dca94d52a&version=stable).

Comment: Have you read other questions with the same (or similar) error? A quick search found [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654978/lifetime-troubles-sharing-references-between-threads) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286096/passing-a-vecstruct-into-a-new-task).

Comment: Also, please take the time to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) of your problem. This makes it easier for you to understand where the problem is, and makes it easier for people to answer your question. In this case, [this version](http://is.gd/E7ZYaq) is smaller.

Comment: @Shepmaster none of the two links solved my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that every variable moved to the thread must have the lifetime `'static`. i.e. threads can't reference values which are not owned by the thread.

In this case the problem is that `self` is a reference to an instance of `MyStruct`.

To solve it, remove every reference and clone the structure before sending it to the thread.

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct {
    field: i32
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn my_fn(&self, adder1: i32, adder2: i32) -> i32 {
        self.field + adder1 + adder2
    }

    fn threade_test(&self) {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
        let adder = 1;
        let lst_adder = vec!(2, 2, 2);

        for a in lst_adder {
            let tx = tx.clone();

            let self_clone = self.clone();
            thread::spawn(move || {
                let _ = tx.send(self_clone.my_fn(adder, a));
            });
        }

        println!("{}", rx.recv().unwrap());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ms = MyStruct{field: 42};
    ms.threade_test();
}
```